Docker container with OpenAI Python client fails with SSL certificate error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
I'm running a Python script using the OpenAI API client in a Docker container. The container suddenly started failing with an SSL certificate error after rebuilding. The same code was working before.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/project/app/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    client = OpenAI(api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY, base_url="https://api.openai.com/v1/")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai/_client.py", line 123, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai/_base_client.py", line 860, in __init__
    self._client = http_client or SyncHttpxClientWrapper(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai/_base_client.py", line 755, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 690, in __init__
    self._transport = self._init_transport(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 733, in _init_transport
    return HTTPTransport(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 153, in __init__
    ssl_context = create_ssl_context(verify=verify, cert=cert, trust_env=trust_env)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_config.py", line 35, in create_ssl_context
    ctx = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=os.environ["SSL_CERT_FILE"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 770, in create_default_context
    context.load_verify_locations(cafile, capath, cadata)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Dockerfile
FROM python:3.11

MAINTAINER Dockerfiles
# setup all the configfiles
COPY app/requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip && pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY app/main.py /app/main.py
CMD ["python", "/app/main.py"]

main.py
from openai import OpenAI

if __name__ == "__main__":
    OPENAI_API_KEY = "sk-****"
    client = OpenAI(api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY, base_url="https://api.openai.com/v1/")

requirements.txt
openai==1.56.2


I solved this by explicitly setting the SSL certificate path using the certifi package.
pip install certifi

Here's the modified code:
import os
import certifi
from openai import OpenAI

# Set the SSL certificate path to use certifi's default certificate
os.environ['SSL_CERT_FILE'] = certifi.where()

# Initialize the OpenAI client
OPENAI_API_KEY = "your-api-key-here"  # Replace with your actual API key
client = OpenAI(api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY, base_url="https://api.openai.com/v1/")

